# HTML menu behavior on smartphones

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Currently trying to make a website responsive to smartphones and tablets. I'm having a bit of trouble with the menu og the site. The menu is basically an unordered list like this:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="page1.html">Page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">Page2</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="page3.html">Page3</a>
        <!-- Dropdown menu -->
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="page4.html">Page4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>      
</ul>
```

The inner unordered list is a dropdown menu that appears when the user hovers the `page3.html` link.

On mobile and tablet I want the menu to act like an accordion, so when the user touches the `page3.html` link, the `subnav` list appears and pushes the other listitems down. I got it to work on desktop by simply setting the dropdown list to a fixed position rather than `position:absolute;` However, on mobile and tablets, the touch on `page3.html` will still work as a link, so the user is, of course, redirected to `page3.html` instead of triggering the `subnav` list.

Is there any way of triggering the subnav list without triggering the link the first time a user touches it? :-) I'm trying to go for a CSS only solution to this, but if there's any need for JS, I'll gladly make use of it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think there's any way to prevent the default behaviour for links without resorting to JS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Wordpress plugin written in jQuery ([Black Studio Touch Dropdown Menu](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/black-studio-touch-dropdown-menu/)) that does pretty much what you want. You can take a look at the source code [here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/black-studio-touch-dropdown-menu/tags/0.2/) and modify to be independent from Wordpress if that's not what you're using. It basically checks to see if the device is a touch screen device and if so, when you click on the parent of the dropdown menu, it expands it rather than clicking the link. The next time, it will actually click the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick :-) Tried the plugin and it works on Android (HTC Desire), iPhones and iPad. On Nokia Lumia (920) however, it doesn't work :-( So will have to find a workaround for that one. Any suggestions are more than welcome! ;-)

Comment: @bomortensen You could probably modify `black-studio-touch-dropdown-menu.js` to check for NOKIA in the user agent string. So basically something like `if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("NOKIA") !== -1)` then you have a Nokia device. You should probably also check for the word "Touch" in the UA string as well. Here is a reference for Nokia User Agent Strings: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/User-Agent_headers_for_Nokia_devices